# How to actually use merge sort for large data sets

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, external-sorting

How to actually use merge sort for large data sets?

Suppose that I have several sorted files with the following data:

**1.txt**

```
1
2
2
```

**2.txt**

```
3
4
5
```

**3.txt**

```
1
1
1
```

Suppose that we can't hold all files' contents in memory at the same time (let's say we can hold only two numbers from each file).

I heard that I can use some kind of R-way merge sort in this case but I don't understand how can I actually do it.

As you see, the first iteration will give us the following sorted sequence:

```
1 1 1 2 3 4
```

, so we flush it to the output file. However, we will get `1` again (from the `3.txt` file) on the next iteration, so the whole resulting sequence is wrong!

Comment: Don't move to 2 as long as you're (potentially) getting 1's from one of the files?

Answer (score 1):

`I heard that I can use some kind of R-way merge sort in this case but I don't understand how can I actually do it.`

N-way merges are quite easy to explain. You open all the files, get the first element from each and put them into a heap. 
The algorithm then proceeds by getting the smallest element from the heap (pop), writing it to your output buffer and then read the next element from the file this item originated from. Repeat until all files are empty.

Comment: So, the whole point is just getting the smallest element on each step? If so, is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: @rcgldr good idea, but the bottleneck is usually on the disk IO, not on the CPU sorting.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut - deleted my prior comment, will delete this one later. I was suggesting that for 3 or 4 files, simpler (not faster) methods could be used.

Comment: @FrozenHeart - as pointed out by ThomasJungblut- the process is usually disk I/O bound, so a heap is a common way to implement a R-way merge (usually this is called a k-way merge). The heap needs to include file info (which file, ...) in addition to the elements to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Start by filling as many variables as you have files, one variable attached to one file. At each step find the lowest value of the three variables, and flush it to the output while filling it again from the same file.

```
| 1.txt | 2.txt | 3.txt |
| 1     | 3     | 1     | output 1 refill from file 1
| 2     | 3     | 1     | output 1 refill from file 3
| 2     | 3     | 1     | output 1 refill from file 3
| 2     | 3     | 1     | output 1 refill from file 3
| 2     | 3     | nil   | output 2 refill from file 1
| 2     | 3     | nil   | output 2 refill from file 1
| nil   | 3     | nil   | output 3 refill from file 2
| nil   | 4     | nil   | output 4 refill from file 2
| nil   | 5     | nil   | output 5 refill from file 2
| nil   | nil   | nil   | end
```

Comment: So, the whole point is just getting the smallest element on each step? If so, is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: @FrozenHeart Probably not really useful, output cost much much higher than comparing three elements.